# Cannot find the way to make @if statement works in blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I'm making a "teacher's" app, and I want to make a log-in page which changes depending if there's registered users in the database or not.

I want to make a redirection button to a create user page if there aren't auth users in database, and to make a select user view if the database have one or more users.

The problem is that I don't know how to exactly do this, 'cause the view always shows me the first statement (what I've got in the if), also if in the database are registered users. Can anyone help me with this please?

This is the blade file:

```html
@if (empty(Auth::user()->id))
  <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item5">
    <div id="title">
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <p>We see there aren't users</p>
    </div>
    <div id="loginForm">
      <button type="button" onclick="window.location='{{ url("/newUser") }}'">Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
@else
  <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item5">
    <div id="title">
      <h1>Select an user</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="loginForm"></div>
  </div>
@endif
```

Here you have the controller index method:

```php
public function index()
{
  $users = User::all();
  return view('/', compact('users'));
}
```

And finally here you have the page:

[image: page capture]

Comment: Please include relevant code as text, rather than images. Unlike images, text can be easily copied and searched (and also cannot become a broken link in the future).

Comment: @El_Vanja sorry! I didn't supposed that, I just edited the question. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Well your question is not cleared,do you want to redirect only if there is a user in database?

Comment: I think your question is you want to check if there is user in database?

Comment: @user1994 no, if there aren't users in database I want to show a button that redirects you to a create user page, and if there are users in the database i want to show all the users possible to log-in. The thing is that I don't know how to use the if to do that

Comment: @Jerson yes! I'm sorry about the confusion, but my english is not good as I wanted

Answer (score 0):

This function will get the current authenticated user: `Auth::user()`. I guess what you are trying to achieve is `@if(empty($users))` where `$users` is the variable you are passing on controller.

If you want to verify if the user that accessed to that view is authenticated you can simply use `@auth` and `@guest`.

Also i would suggest you to change your button to an `<a>` tag and your `href` would be `<a href="{{ route('route.name') }}"` where `route.name` would be defined in your routes file.

in your controller:

you can create a folder inside views called users and then the index.blade.php (views/users/index.blade.php)

```
public function index()
{
    $users = Users::all();

    return view('users.index')->with('users', $users);
}
```

in your view:

```
@if(count($users) < 1)
...
@else
...
@endif
```

`count` is validating if the $users array length is less then 1 (in other words if the array is empty).

Alternative you can you `isEmpty()`

```
@if($users->isEmpty())
...
@else
...
@endif
```

Comment: It seems to work fine, with the exception that when the database has registers, the else statements doesn't throw, so the view doesn't change too

Comment: Sorry, but i couldn't understand what you said, if you have no data on that column it will throw an empty array, you can also use count(), see the answer that i updated.

Comment: Sorry for the waiting, I was sleeping :). It didn't works, throws a "undefined variable: $users" error.

Comment: It's ok, try to output $users on html, just add somewhere in your blade file this {{ $users }}, if you can see an output means the variable is signed otherwise you must misspelled somewhere and you must verify on your controller. Also go to your controller and just declare $users = "some text"; and see if you can use that variable on blade (view).

Comment: It is a misspelling error, make sure in your controller you are passing the right name value: return view('users.index')->with('users', $users);

Answer (score 0):

The following code is the sample for it, kindly replace code accordingly

```
@if(!$user)
   //show button
@else
  //dont show button
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is you want to check if there is user in database.

So no need to check if the user authenticated but to check if there is user on the database.

In your controller

```php
public function index() {
  return view('/', ['users' => User::all()]);
}
```

and in your blade file

```php
@if(!$users)
    <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item5">
        <div id="title">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
            <p>We see there aren't users</p>
        </div>
        <div id="loginForm">
            <button type="button" onclick="window.location='{{ url("/newUser") }}'">Button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
@else
    <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item5">
        <div id="title">
            <h1>Select an user</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="loginForm"></div>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Yes, is this what I want to do, so I just tried to do it, but it throws me an "Undefined variable: users" error.

Comment: what is your blade file name and where is located does it have a folder? example you should define in your controller index , view('yourviewname',['users' => User::all()]);

Comment: It don't works, I'll try to do a function in the controller and delete the @if statement in the blade